# How to not make iOS zoom when browser focuses on select

Tags: ios, mobile

When on a webpage in the iOS5-browser and clicking a select-element, the browser zooms in on the select-element. Is it possible to get around this in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this is one out of many issues with the zoom in iOS5. Basically, the suggested way to solve this issue is to remove ("user-") zooming from the web page completely. The down-side of this is that, obviously, the user then cannot zoom which definitely isn't a preferred way from an accessibility point of view.